# Angular - Align a dynamic directive's markup with the host?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I have a basic `directive` named `[popover]` which all it does is injecting ( *as a sibling*) -  a dynamic component.

I'm using it as :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button popover>Popover on right</button>   <-- here
    </div>
  `,
})
```

The directive's code is:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[popover]'})
class Popover {
  private _component: ComponentRef<>;
    constructor(private _vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private _cfResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }
    @HostListener('click')
  toggle() {
    if (!this._component) {
      const componentFactory = this._cfResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopoverWindow);
      this._component = this._vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    } else {
      this._component.destroy();
      this._component = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Please notice that the directive creates an injected component  on the fly. And this is the injected component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'popover-window',
  template: `
    <div class="popover popover-right">
      <h3 class="popover-title">My title</h3>
      <div class="popover-content">
        Lorem ipsum.... 
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
class PopoverWindow {
}
```

Result :

[image]

The problem is that I want to change the *location* of the popup according to the hoster which in this case IMHO is `elementRef.nativeElement`

**Question:**

How can I align the popup to the *right* location of the hoster via CSS ? ( *is it even possible to do it with css only?*)

It is possible to read the location of each `elementRef` and take its dimensions. But how can I set the new injected component's location to the calculated location ( *which is the right side of each button*) ?

[**FULL PLNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jYX0pgag1LcjZQ5fLYsg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `position:relative` to `<popover-window>` and then you can adjust offsets of tooltip

```
 styles:[':host{position:relative;}']
```

Comment: Added `styles:['popover-window{position:relative;}'],` to `PopoverWindow` -  Didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the update but you included the CSS - globally ( in the HTML file). I don't have a global css file. only inline. Is it possible to change  it as a componenet/directive based ?

Comment: I've found the solution. `styles:[':host{position:relative;}'],` on the `popover-window` directive.